# Microsoft Visio Label transition arrows in UML Statechart (without square brackets)

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-visio, uml

I can't figure out how to label a transition (arrow) in a UML Statechart.  With most items, I just start typing, but with the transition it says:

> Shape protection and/or layer properties prevent complete execution of this command.

I found Format -> Protection and unchecked the "Text" check box, and now I can start typing, but the text just goes away when I finish.  What's up with that?

One thing that sort of works is a "Guard expression", but I don't think that's quite what I want.  Unlike [this MSDN example](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/statechart-diagram-example-HP001208961.aspx), it has awkward square brackets around it.  Is there any way to get a normal-looking label for transitions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double click on the transition to bring up the transition properties dialogue.  Create an Event (the event button), Create a new Event.  Back in the UML Transitions Properties dialogue select your new event from the Event: drop down.  it'll now show up as a label.  Painful isn't it

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for the help.  Not the easiest way of doing things, but at least it's possible.

Comment: To add onto this: when you add an event and click "New..." a `Signal Event` lets you type whatever you want for the label. Unlike the other events that require you to pick some operation